# GNU Parallel stopped working

Tags: gnu-parallel

GNU Parallel worked fine and suddenly whenever I try to use it I am getting this error message I am getting while running any parallel command:

```
parallel: This should not happen. You have found a bug.
Please contact <parallel@gnu.org> and include:
* The version number: 20160222
* The bugid: pidtable format: 10390 1 

* The command line being run
* The files being read (put the files on a webserver if they are big)

If you get the error on smaller/fewer files, please include those instead.
kill_sleep TERM 
kill_sleep TERM 
kill_sleep TERM 
kill_sleep KILL
```

Example:

```
$ ls -1 | parallel echo
parallel: This should not happen. You have found a bug.
Please contact  and include:
* The version number: 20160222
* The bugid: pidtable format: 10390 1 

* The command line being run
* The files being read (put the files on a webserver if they are big)

If you get the error on smaller/fewer files, please include those instead.
```

Steps taken:

- GNU parallel reinstalled
- machine rebooted
- tested with sudo and without
- changed ulimit "open files" to default 1024

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256635
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65535
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Another trial:

```
$ parallel -Dall -j0 ping -nc 3 ::: qubes-os.org gnu.org freenetproject.org
parallel: This should not happen. You have found a bug.
Please contact <parallel@gnu.org> and include:
* The version number: 20160222
* The bugid: pidtable format: 3694 1 

* The command line being run
* The files being read (put the files on a webserver if they are big)

If you get the error on smaller/fewer files, please include those instead.
kill_sleep TERM 
kill_sleep TERM 
kill_sleep TERM 
kill_sleep KILL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20160222 is 4 years old. It is a known problem.

Upgrade to [20201222](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:tange/parallel)

Comment: Considering that your answer ended up in my "low quality post" review queue, would you consider indicating what you believe is the bug that prevented `parallel` from working as expected, and when it was solved?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have a link to download the latest rpm for Linux?

Comment: About GNU Parallel: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/
official packages for various systems: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/parallel/files

Comment: RPM resource parallel http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=parallel